# Make grass for big landscapes

Tags: particles, hair

I found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=27IY1JJ4G8o) for example of how to make decent looking grass. But I was wondering, what would be the best approach for a really big landscape area? Unfortunately I can't find videos about this topic.

So how would I put a hair particle system with high density across a big area? I tried to convert the particle system into an object (mesh), but at some point this also becomes pretty laggy and not really fun to work with, and I already have a pretty fast pc (5900X, 3080TI).

Do you have some good videos or keywords I can look this up with? Something that pushes me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: at one point you can cheat with image textures

Comment: @moonboots Yeah, I thought the same. But anything "good" for that transition? My pc will die on the way expanding the particle system so big that it won't stand out :D

Comment: what about making a render of a grass square and use it as texture for the background, while you use particles for the foreground, or even images with transparency

Answer (score -2):

Blender isn't really optimized for massive, real-time landscapes- you'll have much better results in a program designed for that: Unreal Engine or Unity, mostly

Comment: Ok, but a good way of cheating here?

Comment: @josephhansen: i disagree to your opinin...